# Connecting two Cisco 2960 switches

Tags: networking, cisco, switch

We have two Cisco 2960 switches that we need to be able to connect together.

We have four links joining SwitchA to SwitchB, I'd like to know the best way of configuring the switches so these four links are used as a trunk between them.

I guess the avilable options are Etherchannel (is this even available on the 2960?) or some other sort of link aggregation.

Many thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it seems to be working!  I've changed the config to use LACP instead of Etherchannel.  Here's what I did to configure the ports on each switch:

```
SwitchA>
SwitchA> enable
SwitchA#
SwitchA# configure terminal
SwitchA(config)# interface range Gi0/21 - 24
SwitchA(config-if-range)# channel-group 1 mode active
SwitchA(config-if-range)# exit
SwitchA(config)# exit
```

Checking the port status then shows

```
SwitchA# show interfaces status
Port   Name Status     Vlan  Duplex Speed  Type
Gi0/1       notconnect 1     auto   auto   10/100/1000BaseTX
...
Gi0/21      connected  trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/22      connected  trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/23      connected  trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Gi0/24      connected  trunk a-full a-1000 10/100/1000BaseTX
Po1         connected  trunk a-full a-1000
SwitchA#
SwitchA# show etherchannel
     Channel-group listing:
     ----------------------
Group: 1
----------
Group state = L2
Ports: 4 Maxports = 16
Port-channels: 1 Max Port-channels: 16
Protocol: LACP
Minimum Links: 0
SwitchA#
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you if those switches support EtherChannel or not. Here's the Cisco page with their indexs of examples of configuring EtherChannel: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk389/tk213/tech_configuration_examples_list.html

I'd give it a shot and see. Worst case it doesn't work. Pull up the docs for your specific version of the OS to see what the command syntax looks like.

I prefer using standards-based link aggregation whenever possible (802.3ad), but doing an EtherChannel between Cisco devices is fine.

Comment: Okay, going for LACP instead.  The problem is the channel-group is now set to protocol "-", implying Etherchannel.  How do I change it to LACP?  I can create a new channel-group and set it to "active", but I can't work out how to change the existing group.

Answer (score 0):

The Catalyst 2600 series supports TokenChannel, which is apparently the Token Ring equivalent of EtherChannel. Though the switches are EOL, documentation is still available for them on Cisco's Web site. If you don't have a CCO account, you'll need to sign up for a free account on their Web site to get access. Click the "Register" link in the upper right-hand corner of the cisco.com homepage. Once you're logged in, the main page for the Cat2600 series is [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/customer/products/hw/switches/ps593/tsd_products_support_eol_series_home.html).

The short of it is that there should be a "TokenChannel Configuration" choice on the Configuration Menu. Each TokenChannel can contain 2 to 4 links, so what you want to do should work. It looks like you just go into the TokenChannel config, select "Add", and it walks you through the rest.

Comment: Sorry, we got numbers in our heads wrong. They're 2960's.  The old 2600's are what we have for our voice network ;)
Sorry.

Comment: Makes more sense. As you found out, you can do it with 2960's. In fact, just about any IOS or CatOS-based Catalyst should be able to at least do static EtherChannel, and most will do PAgP or LACP as well.